# JQuery filter function to ignore html elements and search only text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have the following JQuery filter, where holiday_days is a variable date number (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4... 28, 29, 30). The text has to match exactly, so for example if holiday_days = 1, it doesn't return 1, 10, 11, 12...

```
var element = $('td').filter(function() { 
                return Number(this.textContent) == holiday_days; 
            });
```

Where my html looks a bit like the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="holiday_days">
            "holiday_days"
        </td>
        ...
```

In the code I later append a span into this on certain dividers below the text.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="holiday_days">
            "holiday_days"
            <-- appended -->
            <span>There is a link in here</span>
            <-- appended -->
        </td>
        ...
```

So then my filter returns nothing. How can I either

1. Ignore the span and just search the text (exactly - contains won't work here)

***OR***

2. Filter based on the td class, which does not change

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle or the equivalent, so we could play around with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways you can fix this. The easy way would be to wrap the value in its own `span` so you can retrieve it directly without the siblings:

```
<td class="holiday_days">
    <span class="holiday-days">[holiday_days]</span>
    <span>There is a link in here</span>
</td>
```

```js
var element = $('td').filter(function() { 
    return parseInt($(this).find('.holiday-days').text(), 10) == holiday_days; 
});
```

Alternatively you can leave the HTML as it is and read the first textNode value from the `td` itself:

```
var element = $('td').filter(function() { 
    var holidayText = $(this).contents()[0].textContent.trim();
    return parseInt(holidayText, 10) == holiday_days; 
});
```